# Where should I ask about the capabilities of certain node modules?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Software Recommendations Stack Exchange post: [Is it possible to launch puppeteer from a web-based application?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/64197/is-it-possible-to-launch-puppeteer-from-a-web-based-application)

Hello! My above-linked post includes a question related to the capabilities of the puppeteer node dependency. It was put on hold as off-topic. Where should I go to ask that type of question? It does not have to do with a specific piece of code, but rather with the entire puppeteer module. Thanks for any suggestions y'all have!

Comment: If it is [this puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) a quick searx just brought up, maybe there in the issue tracker?

Answer (score 0):

When you have a question about a particular piece of software, the default place to go is https://superuser.com

You might think "*SuperUser is for Windows wannabees, and not worth of my highly professional software"*. Please reconsider: SuperUser is also for professional software, see for instance my QA https://superuser.com/questions/1044729/how-to-enable-cmis-on-documentum

Comment: I would add: it is about a programming tool, like e.g. when you have a question about configuring an IDE, [SO] would be on topic as well.